# not retrieving rows from db after joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have been creating a simple system for a blog but having some difficulties when retrieving the db after joining 2 tables, like these bellow:

table name: articles

- id
- category_id
- title
- message

table name: categories

- id
- name

What do I want to do:

- Join the infomations from the 2 tables above.
- Retrieve them in my admin panel in order to edit/delete the articles.

**What are my problems:**
 - If I Join the tables using:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles JOIN categories ON articles.category_id = categories.id

I can get all the columns, but seems that the edit and delete buttons are recognizing the categories id column, not the articles id column.

I am using foreach to retrive the db, like the resume bellow:

> ```
> <thead> 
>     <tr>
>         <th class="category">category</th>
>         <th class="title">title</th>
>         <th class="message">content</th>
>         <th class="edit">edit</th>
>         <th class="del">del</th>
>     </tr>
> </thead> 
>
> <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
> <tbody> 
>     <tr>   
>         <td><?php echo h($article["name"]); ?></td>
>         <td><?php echo h($article["title"]); ?></td>
>         <td><?php echo h($article["message"]); ?></td>
>         <td><a href="article_edit.php?id=<?php echo h($article["id"]); ?>"><img src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"></a></td> 
>         <td><a href="article_delete.php?id=<?php echo h($article["id"]); ?>"><img src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></a></td> 
>     </tr>
> </tbody>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> ```

If I try to discriminate the articles id using the coding bellow:

> $sql = "SELECT articles.id AS articleid, title, message, FROM articles JOIN categories ON articles.category_id = categories.id 
>   $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
>   $articles = $stmt->fetchAll();

And specifying the articles id link as bellow:

> ```
>         <td><a href="article_edit.php?id=<?php echo h($article["articleid"]); ?>"><img src="images/icn_edit.png" title="Edit"></a></td> 
>         <td><a href="article_delete.php?id=<?php echo h($article["articleid"]); ?>"><img src="images/icn_trash.png" title="Trash"></a></td>
> ```

Now the edit and delete buttons links to the correct "articles id", but cannot get the categories.name column rows anymore.

Hope that someone could help me with this issue and will be really grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there is a column `id` in both categories and articles table?

You have it almost right there, using aliases.

```
SELECT articles.id AS article_id, articles.name AS article_name, categories.id AS category_id, categories.name AS category_name
FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories ON areport.category_id = categories.id
```

You should avoid using `*` when selecting data, only select what you actually need, using `AS` as shown above will rename the column in the output data.

Comment: @user2351553 If i did the work, you should say thank you by accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Table name in query is wrong. Use articles instead of areport

```
SELECT articles.id AS article_id, 
       articles.name AS article_name, 
       categories.id AS category_id, 
       categories.name AS category_name
FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories ON articles.category_id = categories.id
```